# Exporting Umbraco Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't locate the answer anywhere online.
I'm building a webAPI Controller by extending UmbracoAPIController. the application works fine on my local machine, so I want to move it to our hosted UAT platform.

I've built the solution locally but can't see in the bin folder a dll that has the same name as the Controller.

So do I just need to copy the Controller and Models folders to the UAT platform, or is their a dll that contains then (the controller lives in the Umbraco_DEV.Controllers namespace, so is it the Umbraco_DEV.dll I need to move)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this part of an Umbraco website? If so, it'll be built into the main webite DLL.

The controllers won't be built into a separate DLL unless they're in their own project.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is part of the main site, and it works perfectly now I know how to do it.